# Problem in GeoExt Print example

Tags: geoext-2

I've a problem in printing which i see the same problem in Print-Page example and Print-Preview example of GeoExt-2.
https://geoext.github.io/geoext2/examples/printpage/print-page.html
https://geoext.github.io/geoext2/examples/printpreview/print-preview.html
 Problem: The extent of map in printed pdf is larger than extent of map which is viewed by user. The user sees a map extent and after printing, receives a map with larger extent.
I didn't paste my code, because i noticed the same problem in those examples of GeoExt. (Other 2 examples of printing - i.e. Print-form and Print-Extent does not show this problem). So, it's maybe my misunderstanding of GeoExt?
Would you confirm this problem or propose any workaround?